# Adding blackberry nature to android project prevents it from compiling

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry-playbook

I have setup the BlackBerry plugin in Eclipse and then added blackberry nature per the instructions. My project now has the following error:

native-code:impact=5:armeabi

Which I presume means it's not allowed to compile because it has NDK code... only thing is it doesn't use NDK. I was looking into it at one point but decided against it. I'm assuming there's something telling it there's NDK usage in there but I haven't a clue where to look.

Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging through every folder in the project I found an armeabi folder with some GDB stuff in libs. Removing it solved the problem and didn't seem to raise any new issues when running on PlayBook or proper Android devices.